# Which is the best way to use a template with MVC

Tags: php, templates

Is is it better to have your template like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $this->data['title']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php echo $this->data['content']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

or to have it something like:

```
require('head.php');
require('header.php');
require('content.php');
require('footer.php');
```

Comment: Why the hell would they be mutually exclusive?  http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Answer (score 2):

Its just a matter of preference. I personally like to separate header, body, and footer. It seems cleaner in my own little world. Also I use a template file to parse them together, and since you mention mvc I am guessing you have one made up already.

Comment: Yeah I have my own one made up and working well so far and was just unsure about the templating. I started with required all the different parts of the template but now I've changed to the first one up there.

Comment: I have started my own MVC a while ago, I was just checking it out to.. if you want you can check it out [here](https://github.com/xlordt/personal-php-mvc) maybe it can do you some good. I plan on starting it back some time.